# Use Gitlab CI file type variable as entrypoint param to docker service

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to pass a config file to Docker service in Gitlab by overriding the entrypoint to the service.
I have defined a file type environment variable called `FRPC_INI` that I want to pass to the service as the configuration file.

```
services:
  - name: snowdreamtech/frpc
    entrypoint: ["/usr/bin/frpc", "-c", "$FRPC_INI"]
```

This doesn't work because it seems Docker service doesn't have access to the file. Is there a way I can use to pass configuration to the service?

This is the error I get in the job:

```
*** WARNING: Service runner-o2x8al8z-project-49-concurrent-0-0a0da0553813eb7d-snowdreamtech__frpc-0 probably didn't start properly.
Health check error:
start service container: Error response from daemon: Cannot link to a non running container: /runner-o2x8al8z-project-49-concurrent-0-0a0da0553813eb7d-snowdreamtech__frpc-0 AS /runner-o2x8al8z-project-49-concurrent-0-0a0da0553813eb7d-snowdreamtech__frpc-0-wait-for-service/service (docker.go:1156:0s)
Service container logs:
2021-04-27T11:22:31.008112852Z open $FRPC_INI: no such file or directory
*********
```